# How can getArguments() be called in onCreate() of a Fragment..?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Can someone explain how `setArguments()` works? I don't get it. I get how to use it, but I don't really understand how the code below can actually work:

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment{

    public static MyDialogFragment newInstance(String test) {
        MyDialogFragment f = new MyDialogFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("test", test);
        f.setArguments(args);

        return f;
    }       


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Log.d("DEBUG", getArguments().getString("test")); // This actually works!
    }

}
```

I would have thought that `onCreate()` got called before the call to `setArguments()`, but clearly it does not. Is this the way it is supposed to work, or is it just pure luck that the call to `setArguments()` gets executed before `onCreate()` on my particular device? Could the opposite happen under different circumstances (faster/slower/different device, etc.)?

Maybe someone can point me to an article that describes how the flow of events for this works? I don't see where `onCreate()` would get called in the code above, unless it is called asynchronously, which to me sounds like it would be risky to rely on `getArguments()` inside `onCreate()`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `newInstance()` is a factory method you call yourself. It creates the `Fragment` object and sets the arguments on it.

The created fragment object is then passed to a fragment transaction which eventually makes the fragment lifecycle callbacks such as `onCreate()` to be invoked at appropriate times.

In case the framework needs to recreate your fragment e.g. due to an orientation change, it will use the no-arg constructor of the fragment and retain the arguments you have set on the object. `newInstance()` and such are useful when the fragment is created for the first time.

For documentation, the [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) class documentation is a good starting point.

Comment: Aha, so the lifecycle of the Fragment is not even started until the FragmentManager gets involved with it..? In the case above I use something like this: MyDialogFragment f = MyDialogFragment.newInstance("Hello world");     
f.show(getSupportFragmentManager() , "myDialogFragment"); I never thought about it that way before, but actually now I tested it and it seems it's the call to `show()` that triggers the Fragment lifecycle (onCreate() etc.)...

Comment: Yes, when you create your fragments like this, the lifecycle callbacks don't kick in until you make the framework aware of the fragment with a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

`onCreate()` is a method that is only called later by the framework, after the Fragment has been attached to the Activity, as you can see in the [Fragment Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Lifecycle).